# Simultaneously read Snowflake and s3 using Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to read data from s3 and snowflake simultaneously using spark and put it into snowflake after processing(join Operation).

During the tests, I found that each gives the same result but different performance.
(The second attempt was made for logs.)

- **v1** : Read from s3 and snowflake respectively, process "Join" operation and save snowflake

  ```
       1st try : It took 2 hours, 46 minutes.
       2nd try : It took 1 hour, 12 minutes.
  ```
- **v2** : Write the data B read from snowflake in s3, read it again, and save snowflake after "Join" operation

  ```
        1st try : It took 5 minutes.
        2nd try : It took 5 minutes.
  ```
- **v3** : Read from s3 and snowflake respectively, write the result to s3 and read it again, and save snowflake

  ```
      1st try : It took 1h 11mins.
      2nd try : It took 50 minutes.
  ```

**Question. Why does each test perform differently?**
I think v1 should be the fastest in that snowflake spark-connector is supported.

Here is test details and time information elapsed for each line,
Common config

- Data A - stored in s3 : 20.2GB
- Data B - stored in snowflake(internal table) : 7KB(195 rows)
- spark config : r5.4xlarge(4) on-demand
- snowflake warehouse : 3x-large
- aws emr version : emr-5.31.0
- spark version : 2.4.6
- snowflake version : spark-snowflake_2.11

Test(using aws EMR)

- **v1** : Read from s3 and snowflake respectively, process "Join" operation and save snowflake

  Result : OOM occurs after 2 hours ((Exit status 137.)

  Change spark config by aws guide ".set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "500") & resultDF.repartition(500).cache(): It took **2h 46mins**.

```scala
object snowflake_v1 {
  val spark_config = new SparkConf()
    .set("fs.s3.maxConnections", "5000")
    .set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "1200")
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "500")
    .set("spark.network.timeout", "10000000")
    .set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "1000000")

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("yarn")
    .config(spark_config)
    .appName("snowflake")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //parquet at snowflake_v1.scala:27
    val Adf =
      spark.read
        .parquet(
          "s3://"
        )
        .cache()

    var sfOptions = Map.apply(
      "sfURL" -> "XXX",
      "sfUser" -> "XXX",
      "sfPassword" -> "XXX",
      "sfDatabase" -> "XXX",
      "sfSchema" -> "XXX",
      "sfWarehouse" -> "XXX"
    )

    val Bdf: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read
      .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
      .options(sfOptions)
      .option("dbtable", "t_B")
      .load()

    val resDF =
      Adf.join(Bdf, Seq("cnty"), "leftouter").cache()

    val newDF = resultDF.repartition(500).cache() //If not, OOM occurs

    newDF .write
      .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
      .options(sfOptions)
      .option("dbtable", "t_result_spark_v1")
      .option("parallelism", "8")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
  }
}
```

[image: Time required for the second try_v1]

- **v2** : Write the data B read from snowflake in s3, read it again, and save snowflake after "Join" operation

  Result : It took 5mins.

```scala
object snowflake_v2 {
  val spark_config = "same as v1"

  val spark = "same as v1"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // parquet at snowflake_v2.scala:25
    val Adf = "same as v1"

    var sfOptions = "same as v1"

    val Bdf: DataFrame = "same as v1"

    //parquet at snowflake_v2.scala:53
    Bdf.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet("s3://..b")
    
    //parquet at snowflake_v2.scala:56
    val Bdf2=
      spark.read.parquet("s3://..b")

    val resDF =
      Adf.join(Bdf2, Seq("cnty"), "leftouter").cache()

    resDF .write
      .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
      .options(sfOptions)
      .option("dbtable", "t_result_spark_v2")
      .option("parallelism", "8")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
  }
}
```

[image: Time required for the second try_v2]

- **v3** : Read from s3 and snowflake respectively, write the result to s3 and read it again, and save snowflake

  Result : It took 30mins, but duplicated rows occur in s3 and snowflake

  Before writing the result in s3, it takes **1h 11mins** if I print the count so that the actual operation proceeds.(No duplication)

```scala
object snowflake_v3 {
  val spark_config = "same as v1"

  val spark = "same as v1"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    //parquet at snowflake_v3.scala:25
    val Adf = "same as v1"

    var sfOptions = "same as v1"

    val Bdf: DataFrame = "same as v1"

    val resDF =
      Adf.join(Bdf, Seq("cnty"), "leftouter")

    println("resDF count")
    //count at snowflake_v3.scala:54
    println(resDF.count) //If not, duplicated rows occur

    //parquet at snowflake_v3.scala:58
    resDF.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet("s3://../temp_result")

    //parquet at snowflake_v3.scala:65
    val resDF2 =
      spark.read.parquet("s3://../temp_result")

    resDF2 .write
      .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
      .options(sfOptions)
      .option("dbtable", "t_result_spark_v3")
      .option("parallelism", "8")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
  }
}
```

[image: Time required for the second try_v3]

Comment: where is the question ?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question? Also, why do you care why one solution is faster than another? If you can use any solution then use the faster one; if you are limited in the solutions you can deploy then why do you care that other solutions might be faster?

Comment: As you said, if there is one possible way, i can use it.However, I asked to know what caused the result. In my prediction, v1 should be the fastest in that snowflake spark-connector is provided, but it shows the slowest performance, so I am curious about the cause.

Comment: This is an interesting question - but can you provide more details? I would like to know how much time each of the steps took (instead of only a single timer per strategy)

Comment: I ran the same test once more to provide more detailed information. I attached a picture of the time taken for each step for each test. I also commented out each location in the code. I will try to attach more detailed information if necessary.
I think it's taking a long time when spark does a physical run (calculation) using both data sources at the same time.